# Mongoose DB watch specific attribute change

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

In a Mean stack app that am exploring, came across an issue where there is a need to sort stored documents by the length of an array attribute.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
    },
    password: String,
    provider: String,
    salt: String,
    facebook: {},
    photos:[String],
    photoCount: Number,
    plants:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Plant'}],
    imgurAlbumID: String,
    createdAt : {type:Date, default: new Date()}

});
```

I will like to bring your attention to **photos** array and **photoCount**.

Want to implement a pre save hook for solely 1 attribute, in this case **photos**.

However, from what I know, the only solution I can think of is adding a pre save hook that watches all other attributes as well. Am trying to only watch for 1 single attribute to update the **photoCount** which stores a simple Integer value for the length count of the **photos** array.

Does anyone know of a resource that I should be reading up on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pre save hook and only update photoCount if the photos array has changed:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isModified('photos')) {
        this.photoCount = this.photos.length;
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.